# Unable to jump to a subject in the help file in macOS X

Tags: neovim, help-system

I have a Swiss keyboard where the ']' is created with the CTRL-ALT-5 key combination. I remapped it to the 'à' character as so:

```
keymap.set({"n", "o", "x"}, "à", "]", {remap = true})
```

The remap works in normal mode but not in the help files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any special reason for using `remap = true`? This is usually not what you'd want. And why not use `<C-]>` as mapping target as this seems to be the command you ultimately want to run?

Comment: That is true, it didn't cross my mind to create a mapping for <C-]>. Done and working, thank you

Comment: Glad you fixed it. You might post an answer for your own question to help other users. You can accept your own answer after two days.

Comment: Why did they call that option "remap"? Sigh…

Comment: @romainl probably because Vim's `:help map.txt` uses "remap[ping]" in this specific meaning.

Comment: That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a mapping for the actual command you want to use. That's `<C-]>` in this case.

Some minor remarks: using a non-recursive mapping is preferred both in general and in this instance. Mapping in operator-pending mode seems superfluous but that's the default. Either use the default or create the mapping only for normal and visual modes.

The resulting Lua code would be either of the two

```lua
keymap.set({"n", "x"}, "à", "<C-]>")
keymap.set("", "à", "<C-]>")
```

The latter would be equivalent to the following Vimscript:

```
:noremap à <C-]>
```